# What does it mean to "learn a linear transformation"

Tags: linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra

I've been reading up on word embeddings and there was one sentence that confused me a bit:

> ..handled words not seen during training by learning a linear
>   transformation between their RNN word embedding space and a larger
>   word embedding such as word2vec.

I'm familiar with linear transformations but don't understand how we are **learning a linear transformation**.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: where is this from, in what context (subtitle of paragraph or chapter or something along those lines) is this written?

Comment: It is at the Skip Thought Vectors section of the following link:https://medium.com/huggingface/universal-word-sentence-embeddings-ce48ddc8fc3a . It is being used to handle words not seen during training.